# OS X Spell Service opens too many files?

Tags: macos, spell-check, lsof

I found this question, [Is there a fix for the "Too many open files in system" error on OS X 10.7.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/433746/is-there-a-fix-for-the-too-many-open-files-in-system-error-on-os-x-10-7-1) , and specifically this answer

https://superuser.com/a/1180084/177312

and the output from that command was:

```
 562 com.apple
 580 firefox
 716 eclipse
 825 Microsoft
 874 Google
 950 plugin-co
 953 plugin-co
1901 AppleSpel
2563 AppleSpel
2646 AppleSpel
```

WTF? Why does Spell waste all open files? I use it very, I think, averagely. A few documents in Pages, Safari and Messages. This is El Capitan 10.11.

How do I prevent the spelling service to grind my system to a halt?